# libgdx change Image Sprite on runtime

Tags: libgdx

Creating an Image Actor works well if Sprite is passed in Image constructor

```
Sprite sprite ... 
Image image = new Image(sprite);
```

I need to change the sprite on runtime. But this does not work:

```
image.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(newSprite));
```

Any Idea how to fire the change?

Comment: how do u draw ur texture... (hope ur calling spritebatch to draw)

Comment: The actors are on a Stage. In  the Stage render method I call stage.act() first and stage.draw() next. Stage.draw() is the one that do the batch.begin() and batch.end(). The rest of the game is working fine. It's just this Image thing...

Comment: Sorry to unearth old question, but did anybody has an answer to that question ? I am stuck with the same problem

Comment: A TextureRegionDrawable needs to get a TextureRegion in its constructor. So -> image.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(your new TextureRegion)); Should work fine (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to use a `TextureRegion` for this and just decide which frame to draw: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

Comment: Not exactly, I don't want to do any animation here. I just want to change the sprite on a user input action while reusing the instantiated Image. The method set Drawable should allow me to do that I guess.